# How can highlight copy in terminal, paste outside terminal?

Tags: command-line, copy, paste

When I highlight copy in the terminal I can paste with `shift+insert`. But when I press shift insert in google chrome it gives different output. How do you get it to copy globally?

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you using? In *gnome-terminal* you can highlight text and right-click to open a menu where you select copy.

Comment: Yes gnome-terminal. But I don't want to right click copy.